# Scan for BLE peripheral in background - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process, core-bluetooth

I am looking for a solution to scan for BLE peripherals while the app is in background state through an iOS device. I have tried checking the capabilities, adding central and peripheral in info.plist for background process, creating a singleton CBCentralManager. It scans and connects to the BLE devices while in foreground but once it goes to background, it never calls the didDiscover method. Is there any solution fo the same? Thanks in advance.

My info.plist

```
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

My capabilities
[image]

I have also called the scanPeripheral with a service as you have mentioned.

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "6T5FFJJIL-B5A3-D839-LDKL-KJBLKJ33")])
```

I also tried using allow duplicates true/false for the options for scanPeripherals and also retrievePeripherals delegates too.

Comment: Can you be more clear what did you add to capabilities and info.plist, and also your code for scanning. Because Apple is quite specific with its requirements for BLE scanning on background, and with no code or details, it's not possible to say anything

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific. Could you figure out now?

Comment: That generally looks fine. You'll need to detail how you're testing this. A likely case is that the device is already discovered (so it would be a duplicate and won't be discovered again), or that the device isn't actually advertising when you think it is (tools like nRF Connect or LightBlue are helpful for debugging that), or that the device is already connected to the phone (in which case it won't advertise). `retrievePeripherals` doesn't have a delegate, so I don't know what you mean there. You'll want to log carefully to make sure what you think is happening is happening.

Comment: Also, are you really acting as a peripheral (bluetooth-peripheral)? Are you currently advertising? Does that work? (If you're not acting as a peripheral, you shouldn't mark it.)

Comment: So after you call `startScanning`, what's the value of `centralManager.state`? Also does your delegate receive any `centralManagerDidUpdateState`?

Comment: @RobNapier I have 2 BLE devices, I keep one device near and the other too far so that it wont be detected. I bring the second one near as soon as one is discovered and connected. I disconnect the connected BLE device and then bring the app to background. And on a timer I call the scanPeripheral again. It doesn't discover neither the first one which was already connected nor the second one which was kept far and bought near. I have been using the nRF to test it too. I log almost every other line to see if it calls all the line. It just doesn't call the didDiscover still.

Comment: @KirilS. The state of the centralManager.state is poweredOn. I made sure it remains that when the scan is called and I have logged it too.

Comment: "And on a timer I call the scanPeripheral again." Don't do that. Just scan. If you're not scanning when you go into the background, the timer likely isn't firing. Typically you want to be scanning when you go into the background, and you will keep scanning. Timers generally do not fire in the background. (Are you seeing the scanForPeripherals get called after you go into the background?)

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, the timer calls all other methods that leads to scanForPeripherals also I have logged the line just about that and the line below it. So it is definitely calling the scan method. Is there anything else that you could think of that I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Also would there be any specs that I need to look out for in the BLE device? I am asking this because I might have done almost all pre-requisites that is needed to scan BLE in background.

Comment: Only my general advice: when something does not work, something you believe to be true is not true. I would build as small and simple a program as you can imagine to test this, something that does almost nothing at all but log and scan, and find the code change that toggles whether the failure happens. Scanning in the background for a known UUID works. Many of us do it. So you're going to debug.

Comment: @RobNapier, I tried this too. Creating a new project and added location manager and it updates the location and on calling the location delegates, it also calls scanForPeripherals with a specific service. It works fine in foreground but in background it only updates the location and not the scan method. Is there any example that I can use or check on? I am not sure why is this behaving so weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly passing `nil` as the `forServices` parameter of `scanForPeripherals`. [This is not allowed in the background.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager)

> Your app can scan for Bluetooth devices in the background by specifying the bluetooth-central background mode. To do this, your app must explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the serviceUUIDs parameter. The CBCentralManager scan option has no effect while scanning in the background.

You also will not receive duplicates while in the background, even if you request them with CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey.

You will need to determine the list of service UUIDs you want to scan for, and pass those to `scanForPeripherals`.

Comment: I did exactly the things you have asked for but no luck as of now. Could you again go through the question that I have edited please?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get background connection working by doing the following:

1. In the `didDisconnectPeripheral`, I called a function `startScanning`. Inside `startScanning` is where I have
   `myCentral.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [SERVICE_UUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])`
2. Nothing was working until I added the following above `scanForPeripherals`:

   ```
    if let savedPeripheral = self.myPeripheral {
        if savedPeripheral.state == .disconnected {
            self.myCentral.connect(savedPeripheral)
        }
    }
   ```

Now all seems to be working as it should.